# Fortran90 derived types with mpi, alignment issue?

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90, memory-alignment, derived-types

I got problem with the following basic code:

```
program foo

  use mpi

  implicit none

  type bartype
     real(8) :: x
     integer :: i
  end type bartype

  integer :: mpi_bar_type

  integer ::                            &
       count=2,                         &
       blocklengths(2)=(/1,1/),         &
       types(2)=(/mpi_double_precision, &
                  mpi_integer/)
  integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) :: displs(2)
  type(bartype) :: bar, bararray(4)
  integer :: rank, ierr, i, test(4), addr0


  call mpi_init(ierr)
  call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, rank, ierr)

  call mpi_get_address(bar, addr0)
  call mpi_get_address(bar%x, displs(1))
  call mpi_get_address(bar%i, displs(2))
  do i=1,2
     displs(i)=displs(i)-addr0
  enddo

  call mpi_type_create_struct(2,blocklengths,displs,types,mpi_bar_type,ierr)
  call mpi_type_commit(mpi_bar_type,ierr)

  bararray(:)%x=rank
  bararray(:)%i=rank
  test(:)=rank
  call mpi_bcast(test, 4, mpi_integer, 0, mpi_comm_world,ierr)
  call mpi_bcast(bararray, 4, mpi_bar_type, 0, mpi_comm_world,ierr)

  call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program foo
```

I get a segfault at the derived type Bcast (with intelMPI and openMPI), an in a debugger (DDT), it is said that this might be an alignment problem...

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275497/derived-data-types-with-mpi) thread, where the problem seems to be the same, but I have still got no solution...

Thanks for helping!

Comment: (1) alwuys use `implicit none`; (2) `use mpi` rather than `include mpif.h`.  Once (1) and (2) are done, you'll notice (3) you don't have a type defined for mpi_cadna_double_st (should be integer) and (4) the kind is wrong for displs (you should use `integer(kind=mpi_address_kind)`.  That should do it.

Comment: Yes my sample code was very bad. I corrected it (and edited my post in accordance), but I still have a segfault...

Comment: The updated code is now almost right, but `addr0` also needs to be `integer(kind=mpi_address_kind`); if you `print *, displs` before the type create you'll notice that the values are nonsense, which can easily lead to the segfault since they describe memory access.  I'm actually surprised gfortran isn't throwing up a warning there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
program foo
  implicit none
  include 'mpif.h'

  type bartype
     real(8) :: x
     integer :: i
  end type bartype

  integer :: mpi_bar_type

  integer ::                            &
       count=4,                         &
       blocklengths(4)=(/1,1,1,1/),      &
       types(4)=(/MPI_LB,mpi_double_precision, &
                  mpi_integer,MPI_UB/)
  integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) :: displs(4)
  type(bartype) :: bararray(4)
  integer :: rank, ierr, i, test(4)


  call mpi_init(ierr)
  call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, rank, ierr)

  call mpi_get_address(bararray(1), displs(1))
  call mpi_get_address(bararray(1)%x, displs(2))
  call mpi_get_address(bararray(1)%i, displs(3))
  call mpi_get_address(bararray(2), displs(4))

  do i=4,1,-1
     displs(i)=displs(i)-displs(1)
  enddo

  call mpi_type_create_struct(4,blocklengths,displs,types,mpi_bar_type,ierr)
  call mpi_type_commit(mpi_bar_type,ierr)

  bararray(:)%x=rank
  bararray(:)%i=rank
  test(:)=rank
  print *, "before", bararray

  call mpi_bcast(test, 4, mpi_integer, 0, mpi_comm_world,ierr)
  call mpi_bcast(bararray, 4, mpi_bar_type, 0, mpi_comm_world,ierr)

  print *, "after", bararray

  call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program foo
```

Note the use of `MPI_LB` and `MPI_UB` as additional fictitious members of the structure. This is to ensure that the extents of the type is right.
I'm not entirely sure this is the recommended way for doing that according to the standard, but it has always worked for me.
For what I know, the standard says to add a `bind(C)` and a `sequence` to your type definition, but even though, I'm not sure not setting the upper bound of the type would work since you will have alignment issue I suspect.

---

**EDIT:** after the various remarks about MPI_LB and MPI_UB which are indeed deprecated, and a careful re-reading of the standard, I guess the following works and should be compliant.

```
program foo
  implicit none
  include 'mpif.h'

  type bartype
     real(8) :: x
     integer :: i
  end type bartype

  integer :: tmp_type, bar_type

  integer ::                            &
       count=4,                         &
       blocklengths(2)=(/1,1/),         &
       types(2)=(/mpi_double_precision, &
                  mpi_integer/)
  integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) :: displs(2), lb, extent
  type(bartype) :: bararray(4)
  integer :: rank, ierr, i, test(4)


  call mpi_init(ierr)
  call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, rank, ierr)

  call mpi_get_address(bararray(1)%x, displs(1))
  call mpi_get_address(bararray(1)%i, displs(2))
  call mpi_get_address(bararray(1), lb)
  call mpi_get_address(bararray(2), extent)

  do i=1,2
     displs(i)=displs(i)-lb
  enddo
  extent=extent-lb
  lb=0

  call mpi_type_create_struct(2,blocklengths,displs,types,tmp_type,ierr)
  call mpi_type_commit(tmp_type,ierr)
  call mpi_type_create_resized(tmp_type,lb,extent,bar_type,ierr)
  call mpi_type_free(tmp_type,ierr)
  call mpi_type_commit(bar_type,ierr)

  bararray(:)%x=rank
  bararray(:)%i=rank
  test(:)=rank
  print *, "before", bararray

  call mpi_bcast(test, 4, mpi_integer, 0, mpi_comm_world,ierr)
  call mpi_bcast(bararray, 4, bar_type, 0, mpi_comm_world,ierr)

  print *, "after", bararray

  call mpi_type_free(bar_type,ierr)
  call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end program foo
```

Comment: [The use of `MPI_LB` and `MPI_UB` is deprecated](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node76.htm)

Comment: @JonathanDursi I know they are, but the standard isn't too clear(for me at least) on the actual reason for them to be deprecated, and on a valid way of achieving what their purpose is without using them... Can you enlighten me on that, that would be great.

Comment: You're right that you in general need this information - eg, if the OP wanted to create an array of these, there'd almost certainly be padding at the end - even if that isn't the issue here.  The current recommended way to do this is to use [MPI_Type_create_resized](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Type_create_resized.html). As to the why of the deprecation, I couldn't really say; I think the new style is cleaner, but presumably there's some stronger implementation reason for the change.

Comment: The "new" (since 1998) way: Instead of setting MPI_LB and MPI_UB in the creation of the struct type, you would instead use MPI_Type_create_resized.  You still create a two-type struct with double and int, then resize that type for the desired lower bound and (derived from extent) upper bound.   No one is taking away MPI_LB and MPI_UB, though, so your approach will work fine for at least 2 more decades.

Comment: @Gilles - Oh, it turns out there's just been a [discussion on the OpenMPI mailing list](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2015/08/27502.php) about the reason for the deprecation; "hard-coding" the UB/LB like this is perfectly fine for an individual structure, but starts generating surprising behaviour once you use the thus-defined type as a subtype in a new datatype.